# .htaccess redirection rule

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

Can anyone help with .htaccess URL rewriting rule.

I need to redirect pages like this:

```
www.website.com/index.php?a=some-word-some-other-word
www.website.com/index.php?a=something
www.website.com/index.php?a=some-other-thing
```

All that pages have the same content as www.website.com/index.php

to

www.website.com/index.php or www.website.com/

I already asked for this and I got this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

#if the query string has an a parameter
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)a= [NC]
#Redirect and remove query string parameters
RewriteRule .*  http://www.website.com/? [R=301,L]
```

It does that, it redirect those pages to home page (root of site). But I have some pages with URLs like:

```
i.php?a=something-something-something
```

and problem is that .htaccess code above affect those links too.

Can anyone make that code just to redirect links for pages based on `index.php?a=` **and not** for `i.php?a=` too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this and tell me if it works:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

#if the query string has an a parameter
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)a= [NC]
#Redirect and remove query string parameters
RewriteRule ^index\.php$  http://www.website.com/? [R=301,L]
```